# How can I get notification on iphone facebook app from facebook mobile web app

Tags: facebook, mobile, notifications

I have made facebook mobile web app.

It sometimes send the facebook push notifiactions.

Facebook web page(www.facebook.com) recieves the notifications well, but the facebook mobile app(iOS and android) doesn't.

Is it possible to send notification to the facebook mobile app from my facebook web app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the notifications api ? If so, you should know it only sends out notifications on the website. From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/,

Note: Only apps on Facebook.com can use the Notifications API. Also these notifications are only surfaced on desktop version of Facebook.com.